# Is there a way to use the react-router-dom's loader functıon along with redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, fetch, react-router-dom

I want to fetch data with `react-router-dom 6.4.2` loader function and get advantage of it error handling features and also store the fetched data in redux store so that at next render I don't fetch again the same data.

I first want to check if the requested data is available in the store, if it not available I fetch it and store it. The problem is that we can't use hooks in functions. So since loaders are basically functions, there is no way for me to use the `useSelector` inside it.

I was thinking of creating my own hook that checks if the requested data is already available in the store, if it's available it just returns it, But if it's not available yet, it fetches it first, store it then returns it.

```js
const useFetchOrGetData = await (nameOfDataInTheStore, apiEndPoint) => {
    const data = useSelector(state => state.slice[nameOfDataInTheStore]);
    if(data) return data;
    try{
       const fetchData = await fetch(apiEndPoint);
       // dispatch the data to the store here

       // then return it
       return await fetchData.json();
    }catch(err){
        //handle err
    }
}
```

the problem is that the code I have written is `async` and I will have to `await` it in my components, so my component will need to be `async` as well and that make them return a `promise` which is not allowed by react.

Comment: Are you writing a custom React hook, or trying to use a RRDv6.4 loader function? React hooks can't be `async`, but they can certainly use the `useEffect` hook and issue asynchronous side-effects. Please clarify what exactly you are trying to accomplish here. As an alternative to the RRDv6.4 loaders have you considered [redux/toolkit-query](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview)?

Comment: I first tried to use RRDv6 loader. Since I was unable to use it with redux, I decided to create a custom hook instead. But I also got stuck with that async thing.

Comment: FWIW if you were *just* using redux you'd want to be dispatching an asynchronous action (*e.g. Thunk*) to do the fetch and populate the redux store, not trying to ***do*** the fetch in the hook and return the data to the component. Yes, it seems you've a few libraries and patterns mixed up here. What are you really trying to do though?

Comment: My purpose is to save as much as I can my user's data bandwidth. I'm thinking that if I fetch less I will make them pay less for the internet connexion they use.

Comment: So I want to fetch any data just once and use web socket to manage the update between and connected user and the server. But as you said I'm currently lost between different possibilities...

Comment: Since the RRDv6.4 Data APIs are still really new, and since you are already using Redux, I'd suggest looking more into the RTK-query. It is integrated with redux, caches API requests.

Comment: Thank you. I'll do that. @DrewReese